# Matlab audio recorder error: Audio input device has become unresponsive

Tags: matlab, audio, osx-yosemite, speech, recorder

I used the following to record from the default audio device in matlab on a OSX yosmite.

```
>> rec1 = audiorecorder(44100, 16, 1, 0);
>> record(rec1, 5);
```

These following error occurred

```
Audio input device has become unresponsive: 1024 sample(s) remain after timeout.
```

the microphone on the macbook is working, tested it with audacity and records without any problems.

Comment: These commands are correct and work on my MBP using Yosemite. Perhaps there is another application accessing the mic? Have you tried several times and/or after a reboot?

Comment: It worked. another program was using the built in microphone. Restarting the macbook solved the issue.